# Architecture of backend components to securize personnal datas

Tags: database, security, server, architecture, structure

I work for an app that store some health datas and the law and our ethic make us respect some rules about the treatment of personnal datas.

We want to store the health datas of our users in a different database than the personnal datas (especialy the name of the user). The goal is that if a hacker get access to the health database/server app, he will not be able to get the identity of the persons. And if he get access to the personnal data database/server app, he will not be able to get the health informations of the persons.

Anyone in my team never made this kind of thing, the client proposed [this kind of structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcjNi.png)

The goal is to have a middleware that manage authentification and provide the id of the personnal data database with the other one.

In my mind, we could make far better by using some asynchronous tricks but i'm not an expert in security and i only have a confused idea of what i could make. Maybe there is some standard solution that is used in this kind of situation.

It would be realy great to have some advice of the community about this problem.

Comment: Are you referring to HIPAA and PHI? In your schema, database #3, if it is physical, will still be vulnerable from being breached. 
You should consider having your databases encrypted at rest. What will you use as your database provider? Will you be storing the data on premise or in the cloud? You could encrypt your PHI data, but then you need to contend with indexing, meaning "I want a list of names in alphabetical order" will be near impossible if the data is encrypted. Which fields are you looking to capture as PHI